# broadcast.addr. in rDNS?

Tags: reverse-dns

Our in-addr.arpa zones contain entries like the following.

```
0.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa. 120 IN  PTR broadcast.old.
255.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa. 120   IN  PTR broadcast.addr.
```

We don't (nor do any of our forwarders) resolve "old." or "addr.".

Does having these entries make any kind of sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, they're junk.

Maybe someone used the reverse DNS zones as an IP inventory system, and wanted to mark out the old broadcast address (which some devices might have still been using) and new broadcast address after a subnet mask length change?

Or maybe they just wanted for those cute little notes to be returned instead of an NXDOMAIN when they did a brute force PTR DNS lookup against every address in the range?

Whatever the reason, it was probably inventive and imaginative (in a bad way).. and they certainly should be safe to strip out.